# Stop log4j2 printing to Eclipse console when configured to append only to file

Tags: eclipse, maven, log4j2

In my Maven project, I have `log4j2.xml` under `source/main/resources`. The contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration status="WARN">
  <appenders>
    <File name="MyFile" fileName="app.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>             
  </appenders>

  <loggers>     
    <root level="debug">
      <appender-ref ref="MyFile" level="error"/>
    </root>    
  </loggers>
</configuration>
```

I'm initialising the logger with:

```
final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Comparison.class.getSimpleName());
```

But when I run the application, my console looks like:

[image]

**How can I make the log messages not appear on the console (but be sent to a file)?**

Comment: Are these your application logs or any library logs ?

Comment: my application logs

Comment: Can you show how you are writing your logs in source code and maven dependencies. Also, is there any error in starting of the application related to log4j ?

Comment: oh snap... the moment you asked me to show my code I realised I could be using the wrong class... guess what? I was! When I imported Apache's logger instead of Java's logger, all went well. Thanks for being my rubber duck =) Should I just delete this question or do you think there is value in leaving it here for future absent minded folks like myself?

Comment: you can write more details in question and then answer it so that it would be useful in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Vikas Sachdeva, I realised I had set up `log4j`, as per above config, **but imported and  initialised Java's default logger**:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Comparison.class.getSimpleName());
```

All I had to do was to import and initialise the right logger:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

final static Logger logger = LogManager
        .getLogger(Comparison.class.getSimpleName());
```

That was all! Now my console is clean and messages go to the log file as per configuration.